# Как отправить сообщение на почту из командной строки линукса

Tags: linux, email

Собственно, как отправить сообщение на почту из командной строки линукса?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно установить утилиту sendmail.

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

И вызвать команду.

```
sendmail -f from@yandex.ru -m "message" -t to@gmail.com -s smtp.yandex.ru:587 -xu from@yandex.ru -xp password -a /attached_file.txt
```

Comment: А раньше sendmail считался крутым и страшным... А вообще 25 порт много программ могут слушать. См. ответ @y0uix

Comment: Как выполнять sendemail не от root'а?

Comment: ```sendemail``` надо исправить на ```sendmail``` - лишняя буква ```e```

Comment: @shadow Большое спасибо! =)

Answer (score 7):

Самый простой вариант:

```
echo "Test" | sendmail user@mail.com
```

Если нужны "правильные" заголовки в письме, то отправляем так:

```
echo "From: SENDER <sender@mail.com>" > /tmp/temp
echo "To: USER <user@mail.com> " >> /tmp/temp
echo "Subject: TEST MESSAGE" >> /tmp/temp
echo "BODY MESSAGE" >> /tmp/temp
cat /tmp/temp |   sendmail user@mail.com
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sendmail -bs
```

Далее `SMTP` протокол
Вообще этот способ на любителя...

Answer (score 3):

```
# mail -s "Hello" login@domain.com
 <text>
 ^D
```